# SQL: Ensuring all rows are checked against a set of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables that look like this:

#### Supplier

```
  SN         SNAME  Stat   City
+----------+-------+----+--------+
| S1       | Smith | 20 | London |
| S2       | Jones | 10 | Paris  |
| S3       | Blake | 30 | Paris  |
| S4       | Clark | 20 | London |
| S5       | Adams | 30 | Athens |
+----------+-------+----+--------+
```

#### Shipment

```
 SN    PN   QTY
+----+----+-----+
| S1 | P1 | 300 |
| S1 | P2 | 200 |
| S1 | P3 | 400 |
| S1 | P4 | 200 |
| S1 | P5 | 100 |
| S1 | P6 | 100 |
| S2 | P1 | 300 |
| S2 | P2 | 400 |
| S3 | P2 | 200 |
| S4 | P2 | 200 |
| S4 | P4 | 300 |
| S4 | P5 | 400 |
+----+----+-----+
```

I have the find the following:

> List the supplier names (SNAME) for those suppliers who ship at least all those parts (PN) supplied by supplier S2.

In other words, I need to list all those suppliers who ship at least P1 and P2, although obviously my query needs to be focused more on the question at hand.

I'm pretty sure I have to use some form of NOT EXISTS -- perhaps the double not exists, to achieve this.  I tried doing a self-join of the Shipment table to itself -- but I can't understand how to get it beyond checking for ANY item that appears in the PN for S2 and instead check to make sure ALL parts for S2 are in the list before including the name in the result.

Comment: I have added a Non-CTE version of the query in my answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a Common Table Expression to accomplish this:

```
--CTE will contain records from the Supplier you are looking to check against
WITH desiredSN AS
(
   SELECT s.SN, s.PN 
   FROM Shipment AS s
   WHERE s.SN = 'S2'
)
--SELECT will join all other shippers with each record of your Supplier S2 here
SELECT s.SN
FROM Shipment AS s
INNER JOIN desiredSN AS d ON s.PN = d.PN
WHERE s.SN != 'S2'
GROUP BY s.SN
--Having ensures that the count of your old supplier matches
--the number a potential supplier overlaps with
HAVING COUNT(1) =
(
   SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM desiredSN AS d
)
```

If you do not want to use the CTE, you can use subqueries instead:

```
SELECT s.SN
FROM Shipment AS s
INNER JOIN 
(
   SELECT s.SN, s.PN
   FROM Shipment AS s
   WHERE s.SN = 'S2'
)
AS d ON s.PN = d.PN
WHERE s.SN != 'S2'
GROUP BY s.SN
HAVING COUNT(1) =
(
   SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM Shipment AS s
   WHERE s.SN = 'S2'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you not use a nested select statement to refine your results?

For example:

```
SELECT SNAME FROM Supplier
INNER JOIN Shipment ON Supplier.SN = Shipment.SN
WHERE Shipment.PN IN (SELECT PN FROM Shipment WHERE SN = S2)
```

This way, the parts (PN) are restricted to just those that are sold by S2.

*edited* changed the statement to

```
Shipment.PN IN (SELECT PN FROM Shipment WHERE SN = S2)
```

Now, even if they sold one of everything, they'll only be returned if they sold *at least* what S2 sells.

Comment: This seems to give me everyone that sells at least *A* part that S2 also sells, but doesn't give me those that sell at least *ALL* parts that S2 sells.  The result in this problem should only be S1, as only S1 sells both P1 and P2 (which are the parts sold by S2).  P3 and P4 only sell one of the two parts that S2 sells, but not both.

Comment: You maybe able to restrict the nested select statement even more, and add a parameter:

`Shipment.PN = (SELECT PN FROM Shipment WHERE SN = S2) AND Shipment.PN IN (P1,P2,P3,P4,P5)`

This should first verify that the Supplier has ALL the values that S2 has, and then it should return any other PN values.

This based on the fact that SQL reads parameters bottom-up, and would filter down to make sure the PNs are within the restrictions, and then would verify that those PNs were equal to all of S2's values.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think we're allowed to discretely write out the PN list like that (P1, P2, P3, P4, P5).  It doesn't seem to be retuning the correct result either -- it's returning only Jones now (S2).

Is there perhaps a way to accomplish using NOT EXISTS?  I have a feeling that's what he's going for here in terms of his idea of the simplest way of doing it (although I sure like the look of your way better!)-- basically excluding all those SNs for where there doesn't exist every part number in the S2 set.

Comment: Your query will still return a Supplier who only supplies one of the items from S2, `IN` only requires that it match one item, not all.